# how to get BackgroundImage path of a button in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, image, path

I am trying to get the path of the backgroundimage of all the buttons using a method, but I can't seem to get the path. This is my code

```
b1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(C:\\Users\\m\\Documents\\Visual Studio 
2010\\Projects\\PApp\\Papp\\1.jpg) ;

b2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(C:\\Users\\m\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\PApp\\Papp\\2.jpg) ;

Console.WriteLine(b2.BackgroundImage);
Console.WriteLine(b1.BackgroundImage);
```

I can display the image in the button, but i want it to display the path in the console, but all I'm getting is System.Drawing.Bitmap. The path is static by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Once you load the bitmap, the bitmap object forgets about the path because it doesn't need it anymore.

You could make a new class and have it inherit button. Add a property called BackgroundImagePath that executes the above code to set the base class (button) BackgroundImage. Also squirrel it away in a private variable and cough that up in the property get.

That's faking it. But it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

if you have set the BackgroundImage property using the Winforms designer, Visual Studio has generated in the .Designer.cs file the following line for you:

```
this.button1.BackgroundImage = global::WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.my_image_name;
```

As you can see, it's affecting a value of type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a property of type System.Drawing.Image. The only information you have here is the image itself.

If you added the image by yourself:

```
string resourceKey = "my_image_name";
this.button1.BackgroundImage = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey);
```